# How to fix Error 415 Unsupported media type error when uploading an excel file in Java?

Tags: java, multipartform-data, dropzone.js

I am having problem when uploading an excel file using dropzone.js to my backend server using Java. A 415 error is presented when I try to upload the file.

Here is my code to process the uploaded excel file,

```
@Path("/import/customers")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@POST
public Response importCustomersExcel(InMultiPart inMP) throws IOException, JSONException {

    System.out.println("PUT /import/customers");

    CustomerService customerService = Container.getCustomerService();
    FileProcessing processing = new FileProcessing();

    Response response = null;
    File retailersFile = null;

    boolean validationError = false;

    try {
        retailersFile = processing.toFile(inMP);
        customerService.validateImportExcel(retailersFile);
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        validationError = true;
        String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        if (e.getErrors() != null && !e.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
            ExcelRowErrorMessageBuilder messageBuilder = new ExcelRowErrorMessageBuilder(e.getErrors());
            errorMessage += messageBuilder.generateErrorMessage();
        }
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("error", errorMessage);
        response = Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(json).build();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        validationError = true;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("error", e.getMessage());
        response = Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(json).build();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //delete the file if error
        //else THE file is needed
        if (validationError) {
            boolean fileDeleted = FileProcessing.tryDelete(retailersFile);
            System.err.println("File " + (retailersFile == null ? "" :retailersFile.getName() + " was deleted : " + fileDeleted));
        }
    }

    if (!validationError) {

        boolean isImportRunning = false;
        synchronized (customerService) {
            isImportRunning = customerService.isRetailersImportRunning();

            if (!isImportRunning) {
                customerService.setImportRunning(true);
            }
        }

        if (!isImportRunning) {
            CustomerImportRunner customerImportRunner = new CustomerImportRunner(customerService, retailersFile);
            Thread thread = new Thread(customerImportRunner);
            thread.start();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("info", "Import started successfully!");
            response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(json).build();
        } else {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("error", "Import is already running");
            response = Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(json).build();
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

and here is my dropzone.js file upload form,

```
<form action="admin/rest/import/customers" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

I already deliberately added the multipart/form-data in my form but when I check the process when uploading, the content type is `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryG1ZnT8kA25wpWLdW`
. How do I fix the 415 Error when uploading an excel file, it shows a 415 Error. What do I miss to put on my Java code? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: try changing your method parameter to match this one here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files

Comment: @HalkoKarr-Sajtarevic, where did I get wrong on my method?

Comment: oh - just saw that you are using jersey and not spring - sorry my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Jersey you have to do 2 things:

1. add `register(MultiPartFeature.class);` to your `ResourceConfig`
2. change your method `importCustomersExcel(InMultiPart inMP)` to 
   `importCustomersExcel(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream stream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail)`

Then you are able to access file contents via `stream` and file-details via `fileDetail`. Make also sure that your Dropzone-paramName is `file`.

Comment: where to add register(MultiPartFeature.class);

Comment: you have to put it in the constructor of the class which is extending `ResourceConfig`

Comment: Thank you. IN this case I am still learning Java and all. Thanks again.